# php.ini request_order security concerns

Tags: php, security

We're using Chef to provision our machines. Recently it has surfaced that the Chef PHP recipe for CentOS does not have the `request_order` param set. It uses the `variables_order` param, which is set to `EGPCS`.

The documentation for php.ini says that

> ...the default distribution php.ini files does not contain the 'C' for cookies, due to security concerns.

My question is what's the actual security concern?

I am not a PHP dev and the few developers I've asked managed to give ambiguous answers. Google wasn't that helpful either

Answer (score 0):

> **request_order** string
>
> This directive describes the order in which PHP **registers GET, POST and Cookie** variables **into the _REQUEST** array. Registration is done from left to right, newer values override older values.
>
> If this directive is not set, variables_order is used for $_REQUEST contents.
>
> Note that the default distribution php.ini files does not contain the 'C' for cookies, due to security concerns.

So it means by default your `$_REQUEST` will not contain parameters from `$_COOKIE`.

This means that if you have in cookies `$_COOKIE['is_admin'] = false` you can't pass `http://example.com/?is_admin=1` to change cookie value when misusing `$_REQUEST` superglobal.

E.g. `if ($_REQUEST['is_admin']){$this->showAllPasswords()}` when having Cookies populated to `$_REQUEST`

Comment: Could you add some examples of "security concern" this raises? Would love it if it was on a level that doesn't imply PHP specific knowledge.

Comment: @Dumitru Well, security issues rises from using PHP in wrong/insecure way. Non-php related way: You have VIP clients and normal clients in club. You allow only VIP clients in VIP area, but to know if it's VIP, you just ask *client pool* if it's VIP. Regular client says he is VIP and you allow to enter instead of checking some specific list of VIP's